# Remember authentication with web request

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am making a program that get's it's data from a site that needs authentication. I am making the program in a console, so I cannot use controls.

I am able to send the user data to the login form and get the information of the welcome screen. But when I send another request, the site forgot I ever logged in. 
I read that I had to enable cookies somehow, but I haven't worked it out yet.

This is my code:

```
public string GetResponse()
{
    // Build a string containing all the parameters
    string Parameters = string.Empty;
    foreach (string p in theQueryData)
    {
        Parameters += string.Format("&{0}", p);
    }

    if (Parameters.Length > 0)
        Parameters = Parameters.Substring(1);

    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.url);

    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = this.method;
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    string postData = Parameters;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    return responseFromServer;
}
```

These are the headers the request returns:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 7628
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 20:58:21 GMT
Set-Cookie: plaza%5Fmasteraccount=; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; domain=; path=/,plaza%5Fvacmode=R; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; domain=; pa
th=/,plaza%5Fname=%16%05%0C%0E%15%09%18%21QRQ; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; domain=; path=/,plaza%5Flocked=R; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; d
omain=; path=/,plaza%5Flogin=%16%05%0C%0E%15%09%18%21QRQ; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; domain=; path=/,plaza%5Fid=S%5ENWNSQPP%40%15%08%0C%0E%15%09%18%
21QRQ%15%08%0C%0E%15%09%18%21QRQRQQ; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; domain=; path=/,plaza%5Fmid=1323205117; expires=Sun, 25-Nov-2012 23:00:00 GMT; path=
/,plaza%5Fstatus=Q; expires=Tue, 06-Dec-2011 23:00:00 GMT; domain=; path=/,ASPSESSIONIDSQCRSDDR=NKHJIBADOGALNGKDBALDJBIA; path=/
Server: nginx
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: you need to read the cookies in the response header... save them and send them with subsequent requests.

Comment: There's really not enough to go on to provide a full answer to this.  What you really need to do is to include the cookie collection that comes back in the response in the subsequent requests.  However, I have no idea based on this code what the format or content of that cookie should be.

Comment: I have added the http headers to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a cookie container.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

//DO your request that sets cookies from the server.
.........

//Place another request with the cookies
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(someNewUrl);
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
//this should have cookies from the previous request, which should keep you logged in.
```